# ¿Cómo eliminar los 'nan' de una lista anidada?

Tags: python

quiero pedir ayuda con este inconveniente, tengo estas listas anidadas con algunas listas llenas de datos "nan", las cuales quiero eliminar

```
A=[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0],[3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]
```

he intentado eliminarlas de esta forma:

```
E=[]
for x in A:
   E.append(list(y for y in x if str(y) != 'nan'))
```

per cuando hago esta operación logro eliminar los 'nan' pero me quedan listas vacías

```
out():[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [], []]
```

El resultado esperado es:

```
out():[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0], [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma estándar de detectar si un dato es nan sin necesidad de instalar módulos adicionales es usar `math.isnan(dato)`, en lugar de `str(dato)=="nan"`.

Por otro lado, para eliminar las listas que contienen nan sin necesidad de numpy lo que puedes hacer es una comprensión de listas como la siguiente:

```
import math

resultado = [lista for lista in A if not all(math.isnan(x) for x in lista)]
```

Esta expresión itera por las listas que hay en `A` y se queda solo con las que cumplan la condición:

```
if not all(math.isnan(x) for x in lista)
```

que requiere una explicación un poco más detallada.

Dentro del argumento de `all()` estamos pasando una expresión generadora. Esa expresión itera por todos los elementos de la lista, recogiendo cada uno en la variable `x`, y mira si ese `x` es nan. Como resultado la expresión generadora generará una serie de booleanos, por ejemplo `(False, False, False, ...)` si todos los elementos son no-nan, o bien `(True, True, True, ...)` si todos son nan. También puede darse el caso de que algunos sean nan y otros no, con lo que generaría una secuencia del estilo `(True, False, False, True, ...)` etc, con `True` en los lugares donde hubiera nan.

Esa secuencia es la que recibe `all()` como parámetro. `all()` retorna `True` si todos los elementos de la secuencia son `True`. Esto sucederá si todos eran `nan`.

La condición, al ir precedida de `not`, se queda solo con las listas para las que `all()` retorne `False`, es decir, las listas en las que no todos los elementos son nan.

Demo:

```
import math

nan = float("nan")
A=[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0], 
   [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], 
   [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
   [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0],
   [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0], 
   [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], 
   [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]

resultado = [ lista for lista in A if not all(math.isnan(x) for x in lista)]
print(resultado)
----
[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0],
 [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
 [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

**Nota**. Si se diera el caso de que una sublista contuviera algún nan (pero no *todos* nan), el filtro anterior dejaría pasar esa lista (porque `all()` daría False para una lista que no sea todo nan). Si quisieras rechazar estas  listas, cambia `all()` por `any()`.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Edición:**
Para quitar las listas vacías dentro de tu sublista puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

A=[[1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 2.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0],[3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0], [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]]

E=[]
for x in A:
   E.append(list(y for y in x if str(y) != 'nan'))

E = [x for x in E if x != []]
  
print(E)
```

**Respuesta original:**

Tienes varias opciones para eliminar los nan

### Opción 1

Usar `isnan()` de `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan

my_array = np.array([10, 25, nan, 15,nan,nan]

new_array = my_array[np.logical_not(np.isnan(my_array))]
print(new_array)
```

La salida es `[10. 25. 15.]`

### Opción 2

Usar `isnan()` de `math`

```
import math
from numpy import nan

my_list = [10, 25, nan, 15,nan,nan]

new_list = [item for item in my_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]
print(new_list)
```

### Opción 3

Usar `isnull()` de `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

my_list = ['Mike', 'Harry', nan, 'Emma',nan,nan]

new_list = [item for item in my_list if not(pd.isnull(item)) == True]
print(new_list)
```

### Opción 4

Usar `isna()` de `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan
my_list = ['Mike', 'Harry', nan, 'Emma',nan,nan]
new_list = [item for item in my_list if not(pd.isna(item)) == True]
print(new_list)
```

### Opción 5

Usar un ciclo (Bucle) `for`

```
from numpy import nan
my_list = ['Mike', 'Harry', nan, 'Emma',nan,nan]
new_list = []
for item in my_list:
  if str(item) != 'nan':
    new_list.append(item)
 
print(new_list)
```

### Opción 6

Usar `listcomprehension`

```
from numpy import nan
my_list = ['Mike', 'Harry', nan, 'Emma',nan,nan]
new_list = [item for item in my_list if str(item) != 'nan']
print(new_list)
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta pero el problema que se me genera es que son listas anidadas, y al eliminar los 'nan' se quedan las listas vacias "[ ]"

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta e incluí la siguiente línea `E = [x for x in E if x != []]` eso te va a quitar las listas vacías dentro de tu lista